# How to List All Pages of a Section in Hugo

Tags: loops, hugo

I'm trying to list pages from a section on the front pages. This shouldn't be too hard; for example, with the following hierarchy (names genericised):

```
/content/
        |_ test-page.md
        |_ /section-name/
                        |_ page1.md
                        |_ page2.md
```

Using the following loop:

```
{{ range .Pages }}
   ...
{{ end }}
```

Gives the list page for `/section-name/` as `"section-names"`.

OK, well, I looked online for other solutions. For example:

```
{{ range first 5 (where .Data.Pages "Section" "in" (slice "section-name")) }}
```

But this still returns `"section-names"`.

OK, so the [documentation](https://gohugo.io/templates/lists/) has example of where clauses and grouping. For example, `{{ range (.Pages.GroupBy "Section").Reverse }}`. Let's try a similar concept:

```
{{ range (.Pages.GroupBy "Section") }}
   {{ .Key }}

   {{ range .Pages }}

      {{ .Title }}

   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

This seems like it would print every key, then print every page under that key. However, it prints `section-name Section-names` instead of what I was hoping for, `section-name page1 page2`.

What?

Also, using a simple loop like `{{ range .Pages }}`, why does `test` not appear as soon as a section folder is created? I don't understand Hugo's seeming obstination to show me just the section page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked:

```
{{ range (where .Site.Pages "Section" "programming") }}
   {{ range .Pages }}
      {{ .Title }}
   {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```